# How to get proper line number when using trigger_error in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

I am using trigger_error to "throw" errors in a custom class. My problem is that trigger_error prints out the line number where trigger_error was called. For example, given the following code:

```
01    <?php
02        class Test {
03            function doAction() {
04                $this->doSubAction();
05            }
06            
07            function doSubAction() {
08                if(true)
09                    trigger_error('Custom error', E_USER_WARNING);
10            }
11        }
12        
13        $var = new Test();
14        $var->doAction();
15    ?>
```

PHP will print out the following:

> **Warning:** Custom error in **test.php** on line **9**

How would you make PHP return the line where the doAction() function was called (the method called outside the class, ignoring all calls made internally) as follows?

> **Warning:** Custom error in **test.php** on line **14**

**Edit:** Modified my example to be something a bit closer to what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, for those of you who are interested in my final solution, I integrated the following piece of code in our framework which returns the correct line number in all the cases that we could of tested. We are using it in production.

[`ErrorHandler` class](http://pastebin.com/f12a290d1)

It catches uncaught PHP exceptions, PHP errors and `PEAR::Error` s. You will need to modify it a bit has the code has some framework specific functions, but they shouldn't be to hard to track down. Enjoy!

Comment: Wow, this is everything I've been looking for. Very nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is set up an error handler that shows a full stack trace.

Set up a custom error handler, and call debug_print_backtrace() in it. You will find this useful in general, as well in this specific circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Two options, neither one are particularly palatable:

- Override Have test() provide `__LINE__` in the arguments (eg. "`test(__LINE__)`", and give the argument to trigger_error). Set an error handler to print a custom error message. **NOTE:** This is horrifically ugly. :-)
- Set up an error handler, and have it call and process the horrifically-large output of debug_backtrace(). This function can be useful when debugging... But is overkill for what you're trying to do. Please don't use this function as part of the regular operation of a system.

Short answer: too hard, don't try. :-|

Comment: Presumably, the need for a line number would indicate a *really bad* error of some kind, one in which the developer would be required to do some serious debugging. In that case, I wouldn't have thought the overhead of parsing debug_backtrace()'s output WOULD be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put a trigger_error() there also. This ensure that I know exactly where it's called and exactly where the actual error occured. I then send all of the errors to myself in an email when in production. I know this isn't automatic, but at least you can trace what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd throw my two cents into the pot and discuss what I generally use, either as is or with small customizations, for PHP libraries that I build that are often used by other developers.

I subdivide errors that may arise during execution of the program into two categories: those that are a result of erroneous programming and those that occur due to either user error or some outside factor.  For the former, I use trigger_error in conjunction with E_USER_ERROR and the latter an Exception, specifically a package Exception that is then inherited by all other Exceptions in the library.

An example of a development error would be passing an integer in a parameter that is expected to be a string (pre V7) or accessing a method or property of a class that doesn't exist.  (You can use your own developer imagination here.)  Obviously another developer isn't going to care that the error was generated deep in the bowels of a __get or __set statement or some other magic construct, but rather, they'll want to know specifically where their mistake is.  Let's face it...developers don't like to wade through a backtrace.

So the method I employ to localize the error message with is simply:

```
function localize_error_msg($msg, $level) {
    $level = (int)$level;
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, $level + 1)[$level];
    return $msg . " in " . $backtrace['file'] . " on line " . $backtrace['line'];
}
```

I pass in the backtrace level that depends on the construct used which is generally 1 or 2 and the rest is self explanatory.

To prevent the repetitive sequence of "in file on line n", I add this error handler:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (preg_match('/on line \d+$/', $errstr) === 1)
        die($errstr);
    else return false;
}, E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_USER_NOTICE);
```

Again, I like to keep it simple.  One can argue that the localization of the error message should take place in the handler but then, you have to be able to pass in the depth, which is now an additional 2 levels deep inside the handler, and, well, it gets messy after that.

Happy Trails!

Answer (score 0):

You should set an error handler to print a custom error message only for your functions and classes. This is the simple example that works on PHP 5, 7 and 8:

```
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {

  static $callables = array(
    "myFunc",
    "myClass::myFunc1",
    "myClass->myFunc2",
    "myNamespace\MyClass->myFunc",
  );

  $trace = debug_backtrace();
  if (isset($trace[2])) {
    $trace = $trace[2];

    $callable = "";
    if (isset($trace["class"])) {
      $callable .= $trace["class"];
    }
    if (isset($trace["type"])) {
      $callable .= $trace["type"];
    }
    if (isset($trace["function"])) {
      $callable .= $trace["function"];
    }

    if (in_array($callable, $callables)) {
      die("Fatal error: " . $errstr . " in " . $trace["file"] . " on line " . $trace["line"]);
    }
  }  
  return false;
}

set_error_handler("my_error_handler", E_USER_ERROR);
```

Testing:

```
function myFunc() {
  trigger_error("My Error", E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Fatal error: My Error in <some file> on line XXX
myFunc(); // <-- LINE XXX is here
```